# Can the determinant of the covariance of the union of sets be described as a function of the sum of the determinants of the covariance of subsets

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance, high-dimensional

Assume my data can be partitioned into subsets such that all my data $ w= \bigcup_{i \in N} w_i $, where $w_i$ are disjoint and so $ \bigcap_{i \in N} w_i = {\emptyset}$. How can I write the $\det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w)\right)$ as a function of the sum of $\det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w_i)\right)$. My apologies, I realize this is an abuse of notation since I mean the empirical var-cov matrix of a dataset $w$ (or subsets $w_i$) and not the theoretical covariance of a random variable $W$.

I know that the $\det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w)\right)$ should represent a measure of the volume occupied in space by my data $w$. My intuition would be that if I partition my data into disjoint subsets wi and estimate the volume of each of these subsets (i.e. $\sqrt{\mid \det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w_i\right))\mid}\ \forall\ i$) and sum them up (provided that the area occupied does not overlap in space) this added volume should be smaller than the volume of the entire set $w$ given by $ \sqrt{\mid \det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w_i\right))\mid}$. I know there should be a multiplier including the inverse of the $\chi^2$ distribution for a particular percentile of interest but for the purposes of this question, this multiplier isn't relevant so I'm leaving it out.

However, I found that in higher dimensions this can fail even for data for which there seems to be no overlap in space. For example, if I generate two 10-D multivariate gaussians, one using the identity matrix as the cov (set $w_1$) and another as 4*Identity (set $w_2$). One with mean at 9 in every dimension (9, 9, ...) and another with mean at 18 in every dimension (18, 18, ...) then
$$
\sqrt{\mid \det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w_1\right))\mid} + \sqrt{\mid \det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w_2\right))\mid} > \sqrt{\mid \det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w_1 \cup w_2\right))\mid}
$$
even though the gaussians seem quite far from one another. In fact, the $\det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w_2)\right) > \det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w_1 \cup w_2 )\right)$ implying that the volume of one of the gaussians alone is larger than the volume of the whole but I would have thought that the all encompassing volume of both datasets $w_1$ and $w_2$ would be have the largest volume. Meaning that my original intuition was that for these partitions $w_i$: 
$$
\sqrt{\mid \det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w\right))\mid} > \sum_{i \in N} \sqrt{\mid \det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w_i\right))\mid}
$$

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this. Provided my example is correct I would really like to understand the theory behind this and whether one can write out a general form of the  $det\left(\operatorname{cov}(w)\right)$  as a function of the sum of the determinants of the individual covariances of subsets of $w$ (and probably additional terms). I am attaching my code for generating this example I mentioned for clarity and also so perhaps someone can spot that I have made a mistake

[image: scatter plot of the gaussians in my code (showing first and second dimensions)]

(it also produces the scatter plot of the gaussians in the first and second dimensions that I am attaching).

```
% volume contradiction example
clear
close all
rng(123);

%% Synthetic data
n               = 1e4; % num points
n_dim           = 10; % num of dimensions
pcov            = eye(n_dim);
pcovLarge       = 4*eye(n_dim);
% How many Gaussians? 
gnum            = 2;
multiG          = zeros(n*gnum,n_dim);

  for ii = 1: gnum
    pcTempPos                       = 9*ii*ones(1, n_dim); 
      if mod(ii,2)==1
        setTempPos                  = mvnrnd(pcTempPos, pcov, n);
      else
        setTempPos                  = mvnrnd(pcTempPos, pcovLarge, n);
      end
    multiG((n*(ii-1))+1:n*ii,:)     =  setTempPos; 
 end

w1      = (multiG(1:10000,:));
w2      = multiG(10001:20000,:);
C       = intersect(w1,w2,'rows');

vtot    = det(cov(multiG));
v1      = det(cov(w1));
v2      = det(cov(w2));

scatter(multiG(1:10000,1), multiG(1:10000,2)); hold on;
scatter(multiG(10001:20000,1), multiG(10001:20000,2))
legend('w1', 'w2')
title(['det(cov(w1)) = ' num2str(v1) '; det(cov(w2)) = 'num2str(v2,'%10.5e\n') '; det(cov(w1Uw2)) = 'num2str(det(cov(multiG)),'%10.5e\n')])
```

Comment: If you're familiar with Latex syntax, you can embed it in your post by surrounding the code with dollar signs ($)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not too familiar with Latex but a quick look online proved really useful so I did what I could to edit and hopefully it improved the clarity of the text.

Comment: Yup, it helped. I'll edit in some additional changes.

Comment: Also I just re-ran your simulation in R and I got very very different determinants. In fact (unless I totally misunderstand your code) the determinants of the components should be $1\times1=1$ and $4\times4=16$. And indeed that's what I computed after simulating. See https://gist.github.com/gwerbin/581cda166348889a1017552a3720fd23. The overall determinant comes out to about 106.

Comment: You are correct that these would be the determinant results if I was simulating gaussians in 2-D but my example is in 10-D.